# IE inserts strange <iframe> in my <body>

Tags: internet-explorer

For some reason Internet Explorer (both 10 and 11) is adding the below `<iframe>` to the end of my `<body>`. I cannot figure out why. If I load the page in Chrome thous elements doesn't exist, which makes sense cause I didn't put them there.

```
--- page content here ---
<iframe>
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>12</body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

What is causing IE to add this?

Also what's up with the number 12?

[image]

Comment: Seems like you may have some kind of malware IE add-on, at a guess...

Comment: I've tested on other machines and it is there as well, so I find it highly unlikely to be an add-on

Comment: what do you see when you turn off javascript?

Comment: With javascript turned off the iframe goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion to disable javascript, it lead me on the right path. I was sure it was some silly IE feature :)

Removed [wysihtml5](http://xing.github.io/wysihtml5/) which got rid of the iframe.